# Replace or append to string with Lodash

Tags: javascript, string, lodash

I have an array with SQL statements:

```
    var sql=[ "select sum(custo) as TOTAL from PRS_CUSTOS_MATERIAL ",
              "select mes,sum(custo) as TOTAL from PRS_CUSTOS_MATERIAL GROUP BY mes"
   ];
```

and i need to put a where clause on each statement.
The problem is when i have other clauses than WHERE i need to put the WHERE clause before all others. I try to do it like this but no luck.

```
var clauses=['GROUP','HAVING'];
    _.forEach(sql, function (sq, key) {
        clauses.map(function (clause) {
            if (sq.indexOf(clause) !== -1) {
                debugger;
                sql[key]=[sq.slice(0, sq.indexOf(clause)), ' where '+obj.where_str+' ', sq.slice(sq.indexOf(clause))].join('');

                return false;
            }else{
                debugger;
                sql[key]=sq+" where " + obj.where_str;
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a proper explanation of what's not working and provide a [mcve] that includes sample input

Comment: Also note will fail if you have both clauses in one statement as you will insert `where` twice

Answer (score 0):

I recommend for you to use RegExp to solve your problem.

Using the following RegExp you can find if the Select has GROUP or HAVING operators.

```
var pattern = /(select.*)((?:GROUP|HAVING).*)/i;
```

And then you can test this pattern against your array:

```
var arr = ['select mes,sum(custo) as TOTAL from PRS_CUSTOS_MATERIAL GROUP BY mes',
    'select sum(custo) as TOTAL from PRS_CUSTOS_MATERIAL ',
    'select sum(custo) as TOTAL from PRS_CUSTOS_MATERIAL HAVING sadsa'];

arr.forEach(function(select, index){
    var n = pattern.exec(select); // execute the pattern agains the current Select
    if(!n){ // if it not match any GROUP or HAVING,
        arr[index] += arr[index] + ' your_WHERE '; // append your Where at the end
        return;
    } // if match, append yout Where in the middle
    arr[index] = n[1] + ' your_WHERE ' + n[2];
});
```

The result will be:

```
0:"select mes,sum(custo) as TOTAL from PRS_CUSTOS_MATERIAL  your_WHERE GROUP BY mes"
1:"select sum(custo) as TOTAL from PRS_CUSTOS_MATERIAL "
2:"select sum(custo) as TOTAL from PRS_CUSTOS_MATERIAL  your_WHERE HAVING sadsa"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a try from my side..please have a look.

The following code will add the new where clause just after the `from ..` statement. So it will always be first.

```js
var str= "select sum(custo) as TOTAL from PRS_CUSTOS_MATERIAL groupBy....";

var newStr = 'where something > 12' 

var first_part = str.substr(0,str.indexOf('from')+5);

var second_part_tmp = str.substr(str.indexOf('from')+6);

var second_part = second_part_tmp.substr(0,second_part_tmp.indexOf(' '));
var third_part = second_part_tmp.substr(second_part_tmp.indexOf(' '));
if(second_part.indexOf(' ')!=0){

}
console.log(first_part,second_part, third_part);
console.log([first_part,second_part,newStr,  third_part].join(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, but i've simplified things.
I just replace `:where`

```
var sql=[
                    "select sum(custo) as TOTAL from PRS_CUSTOS_MATERIAL :where",
                    "select mes,sum(custo) as TOTAL from PRS_CUSTOS_MATERIAL :where GROUP BY mes"
                ];
```

using

```
_.forEach(sql, function (sq, key) {
        sq=sq.replace(":where", ' where '+obj.where_str);
        sql[key]=sq
    });
```